# How to solve the error "Code: 0x0000000A" while installing Windows 8 Developer Preview?

Tags: installation, boot, windows-8-preview

I am using VirtualBox 4.1.2 for Windows hosts

Here is the configuration used for the virtual machine:
[image: VirtualBox configuration]

When I start the virtual machine some files are loaded and there is a progress-bar `Loading Files...` then after it is finished there is a black screen for some 30 or 35 seconds.

Then comes the splash screen `Windows Developer Preview` which is displayed again for some 30 or 35 seconds.

After that there is a blinking message which says

> Your computer needs restart
>      Please hold the power button
>      Code: 0x0000000A
>      Para
>   *...some values in Hexadecimal...*

It blinks for some time then comes to a halt.
Here is a screenshot.

[image: blinking message]

How do I get it to work?
Where is the problem?
Is it some problem with the RAM alloted to Windows 8 Developer Preview?

I am using this [guide](http://www.sysprobs.com/guide-install-windows-8-virtualbox) for reference.

*Edit:*
[Another guide](http://www.mytricks.in/2011/09/guide-install-windows-8-developer.html) which can be used for reference.

Comment: What are the specs of your machine? CPU model, ram OS, maybe your hardware doesn't support virtualization...

Comment: @Nick Thanks for the help, I had forgotten to enable virtualization from the BIOS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Windows 8 needs hardware support for virtualization, and error `0x0000000A` appears to be linked with the lack of the forementionned : althrough I see that your VT-x/AMD-V acceleration is enabled, I would recommend you to double check it (especially, verify that the feature is enabled in the BIOS setting menu).

Comment: Yes my machine supports virtualization. Checking the BIOS I found that virtualization was disabled. Enabling it made the setup start straight away!! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Which machine do you have?

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this is a very old thread but it came up as the fifth result when researching why Windows 10 would throw error 0x0000000A when booting in Virtualbox. Both Windows 8 and 10 require the no execute or NX bit be turned on in the BIOS *in addition* to virtualization.

It seems that all but one thread I have read on this error completely ignores that option. It enabled me to install and boot Windows 10 just fine in Virtualbox 4.3.26.

Answer (score 0):

This answer also applies to Microsoft Windows 10.

First, "[What is the VT-x/AMD-V?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization)" (Wikipedia). All new major OS  from Microsoft campus love to use the VT options of the processor. This superclass the 'Supervisor Mode' was used in the past of the first generation of multi-thread processor.

It's basically creating a kind of task manager in the processor for threads. Look for more information in the Wikipedia article linked above.

If you catch this error when trying Windows 10, just think you are using a very old computer, maybe it's time to go back or use alternative OS. Olds guys or hacker will tell  you it is possible to work around this, you have to boot the Windows loader with the option VT disabled.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0):

Go back to an earlier version of WinPE. WinPE 2.1 (6.0.6000 for Vista,) worked for me when I needed an image of a ancient parallel ATA hard disk, from a very old Gigabyte 1U server with a 1.8 GHz Pentium 4.