# How to solve the error “Code: 0x0000000A” while installing Windows 8.1 with enabled VT-x

Tags: windows-8, virtualbox, virtualization

I am using VirtualBox 5.0.0 for Windows hosts

I have same problem as described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/336378/how-to-solve-the-error-code-0x0000000a-while-installing-windows-8-developer-p) but my VT-x is enabled in BIOS. 
But my virtual box thinks other way.

[image]

Comment: You have not provided enough information about your hardware to help.  This error is directly linked to a virtualization problem.  The error message is specific about this, virtualization despite you thinking it is enabled, is not enabled.  If you have Hyper-V enabled that could be the reason.

Comment: If your firmware is not current you can try updating that.

Comment: @Ramhound what kind of information about my hardware do you need?

Comment: Motherboard, CPU, firmware revision, switching it to disabled because I recall there being a firmware out there with that bug, that sort of thing

Comment: @Ramhound here is cpu-z [report](http://pastebin.com/YvKbNTJR) and some [screenshots](http://imgur.com/a/G0Z8c)

Comment: update to Virtualbox 5.0.8 and look if it is fixed